# Specified cast is not valid. Stored Procedure in Linq

Tags: .net, linq, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

Hello Below is my code in C#

```
var a = 
from c in HRM_dc.uspCalculateRiskMatrix(CashPrice, InputAPH, Bushels, PercentageCover, BasicEstimate, CallStrike, CallBu, CallPremium,PutStrike, PutBu, PutPremium, TotalAcres, AvgPrice, PerAcreProductionCost, SpringPrice)

                            select new
                            {
                                bushels = c.Bushel,
                                row1 = c._0_00.Value

                            };
                    gvRisk.DataSource = a;
                    gvRisk.DataBind();
```

Please help me why this error is occuring

Stored Procedure

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[uspCalculateRiskMatrix]


@CashPrice MONEY, @InputAPH INT, @Bushels INT, @PercentageCover FLOAT, @BasicEstimate FLOAT, 


@CallStrike FLOAT, @CallBu INT,


@CallPremium FLOAT, @PutStrike FLOAT, @PutBu INT, @PutPremium FLOAT, @TotalAcres FLOAT, @AvgPrice

 MONEY, @PerAcreProductionCost MONEY,

@SpringPrice MONEY

AS

BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @BushelInterval INT, @BushelRange INT, @BushelValueCounter INT


DECLARE @PriceInterval FLOAT, @PriceRange INT, @PriceValueCounter FLOAT


DECLARE @CurrRow INT


IF 1 = 2


BEGIN


SELECT NULL AS Bushel, NULL AS [0.00], NULL AS [1.00], NULL AS [2.00], NULL AS [3.00], NULL AS [4.00]


,NULL AS [5.00], NULL AS [6.00], NULL AS [7.00], NULL AS [8.00], NULL AS [9.00], NULL AS [10.00]


END

CREATE TABLE #tblTemp (Bushel VARCHAR(30), [0.00] FLOAT, [1.00] FLOAT, [2.00] FLOAT, [3.00] FLOAT, 

[4.00] FLOAT

, [5.00] FLOAT, [6.00] FLOAT, [7.00] FLOAT, [8.00] FLOAT, [9.00] FLOAT, [10.00] FLOAT)

SET @BushelInterval = 10

SET @BushelRange = 5

SET @BushelValueCounter = 0

SET @PriceInterval = 0.15

SET @PriceRange = 5

SET @PriceValueCounter = 0

SET @CurrRow = 1

DECLARE @tblBushelRow TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), BushelValue INT)

DECLARE @tblPriceCol TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), CashPrice MONEY)

CREATE TABLE #tblMatrix (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), Bushel VARCHAR(30), CashPrice MONEY, CalValue FLOAT)

INSERT INTO @tblBushelRow (BushelValue) VALUES(@Bushels)

WHILE @CurrRow <= @BushelRange
BEGIN


SET @BushelValueCounter = @BushelValueCounter + @BushelInterval

INSERT INTO @tblBushelRow (BushelValue) VALUES(@Bushels + @BushelValueCounter)

INSERT INTO @tblBushelRow (BushelValue) VALUES(@Bushels - @BushelValueCounter)

SET @CurrRow = @CurrRow + 1

END

SET @CurrRow = 1

INSERT INTO @tblPriceCol (CashPrice) VALUES(@CashPrice)

WHILE @CurrRow <= @PriceRange

BEGIN

SET @PriceValueCounter = @PriceValueCounter + @PriceInterval

INSERT INTO @tblPriceCol (CashPrice) VALUES(@CashPrice + @PriceValueCounter)

INSERT INTO @tblPriceCol (CashPrice) VALUES(@CashPrice - @PriceValueCounter)

SET @CurrRow = @CurrRow + 1
END

INSERT INTO #tblMatrix (Bushel, CashPrice)

SELECT T1.BushelValue, T2.CashPrice FROM @tblBushelRow T1 CROSS JOIN @tblPriceCol T2 ORDER BY 

T1.BushelValue DESC, T2.CashPrice ASC

--SELECT * FROM #tblMatrix

UPDATE #tblMatrix SET CalValue = dbo.udfGetCornMatrixValue(CashPrice, @InputAPH, Bushel, 

@PercentageCover, @BasicEstimate, @CallStrike, @CallBu, @CallPremium,

@PutStrike, @PutBu, @PutPremium, @TotalAcres, @AvgPrice, @PerAcreProductionCost, @SpringPrice)


DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX), @query NVARCHAR(4000)

SELECT @cols = (SELECT STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', '+QUOTENAME(CashPrice) FROM #tblMatrix FOR XML PATH

('')),1,1,''))

--print @cols

SET @query = N'SELECT DISTINCT ''Bushel'', '+@cols +'FROM(SELECT Bushel, CashPrice FROM #tblMatrix) p

PIVOT(SUM(CashPrice) FOR CashPrice IN( '+@cols +' )) AS pvt;'


INSERT INTO #tblTemp(Bushel, [0.00], [1.00], [2.00], [3.00], [4.00], [5.00], [6.00], [7.00], [8.00], [9.00], [10.00])

EXECUTE(@query)

SET @query = N'SELECT Bushel, '+@cols +'FROM(SELECT CAST(Bushel AS VARCHAR) AS Bushel, CashPrice, CalValue FROM #tblMatrix) p
PIVOT(SUM(CalValue) FOR CashPrice IN( '+@cols +' )) AS pvt;'

INSERT INTO #tblTemp(Bushel, [0.00], [1.00], [2.00], [3.00], [4.00], [5.00], [6.00], [7.00], [8.00], [9.00], [10.00])

EXECUTE(@query)

SELECT Bushel, [0.00], [1.00], [2.00], [3.00], [4.00], [5.00], [6.00], [7.00], [8.00], [9.00], [10.00] FROM #tblTemp


DROP TABLE #tblMatrix, #tblTemp
```

Comment: stack trace

   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Int32()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetInt32(Int32 i)
   at Read_uspCalculateRiskMatrixResult(ObjectMaterializer`1 )
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderCompiler.ObjectReader`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView`1.get_Items()

Comment: You need to narrow down in which area of the code the invalid cast occurs. It is pretty demanding to post the whole thing here and expect us to work out how it works without any explanation

Comment: thats challenging for me too .. i am totally confused... i dont expect you to work... but for clarity i pasted the code here

Comment: Thanks Joanna for the comment , i hope i could have done on my own

http://tonesdotnetblog.wordpress.com/2010/06/02/solution-my-generated-linq-to-sql-stored-procedure-returns-an-int-when-it-should-return-a-table/

Answer (score 0):

There is simply *far too much* code here - that SP is not a nice read...

But based on the stack trace you've given in response to SLaks' comment, whatever value is in the column that's returned by the Stored Procedure that you're trying to read as an integer is not actually an integer.

I'm going to take a guess that it's the `[0.00]` column - in which case the error is occurring, then, when you access `c._0_00.Value`.  Judging by the fact that you're doing `.Value`, my guess is that it's typed as an `int?`?  If it were null (`DBNull` in the underlying data reader) then I don't think you'd get a cast exception, but I could be wrong.  Therefore I think the actual value is a non-null string or some other value.

If it is nulls that's the issue, then a basic `where` clause on the linq statement will do.  Stick this before the `select new` line:

```
where c._0_00 != null
```

In fact you should put this in anyway, unless you can guarantee that no `NULL` will ever appear in that column.

But if it's the underlying data type of the value being returned, then you should consider modifying the SP to ensure it *always* returns an int in those columns.

Best thing to do would be to run the SP in Management Studio with the same parameters and look at the result set.  It'll be obvious from that.

Comment: ok , so what can be the fix.. i am really confused .. i did multiple changes in the SP but noting is going in ... also i apologise for thr code readability issue

Comment: have updated my answer.  I can't tell you exactly what the problem is - there is simply no way I can figure out (or, tbh be *bothered* to figure out) what that query returns - but I can tell you what my nose tells me.

Comment: This resoved the issue 
http://tonesdotnetblog.wordpress.com/2010/06/02/solution-my-generated-linq-to-sql-stored-procedure-returns-an-int-when-it-should-return-a-table/